# Securing Locally Generated Files in Python Desktop Application

Tags: python, encryption, local-storage

I'm finishing my python script and I'm near to convert it into an executable and package into an installer, but first I want to ensure the security of the files that the script use.
When installed and in first use, the desktop application creates a local file called "Model", which the application will use later for further operations, the application's workflow typically involves creating the "Model" file once and then using it regularly afterward, and each "Model" file is unique for every user so is desirable to protect it against hacks or simple copy/paste with the file.
Here's the code:

```
import pickle

def create(object):
    model = createModel(object)
    with open('Model.pkl', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(model, file)
    return "Model Created"

def loadModel():
    model = ""
    with open('Model.pkl', 'rb') as file:
        model = pickle.load(file)
    return model
#....
```

I know that it can be protected using embedded encryption and decryption inside the script, but I want to know if there are better approachs to this.

//Edit: Adding more context

If the "Model" file is changed by a malicious person, then the system would not work, as expected, ensuring the integrity of the user's data, so using or not using a hash could made no difference. The priority is that the model's data itself cannot be stolen or hard to be stolen, I designed my system so that if stolen, there is still a layer of protection, which is guess user's data to make the model work (and here the hash approach could help if the hack is something like remote access), but covering the part of accesing the model's data helps a lot.

Comment: Its hard to protect a desktop file from its logged in user. You could keep it and the directory read-only and temporarily switch to writable on update. That helps with accidental changes. But not malicious. You could keep a hash, but a malicious user would have the hash too. if you want to go further, you need some sort of server that the user can't touch and updates are done through an API. That server could even be on the local machine w/ a different user. Not bulletproof, but the next step up.

Comment: Some operating systems, like MacOS, support "sandboxing" applications so they can only access specific directories. But I don't think there's a generic solution.